# Swiper idangerous slider by items at view not one by one

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I'm creating a slider using Swiper Idangerous plugin, and I get a Problem.

I'll explain my problem:
Swiper now at pagination show bullets for all items,and when swipe swipe to next one items.

What I need:
need to the pagination show only number of pages (not items) and when swipe need to see the next 4 items( so swipe all 4 items and show next 4 items).

If that possible with that plugin?, or there anther can do that?

I've add a code so you can know what I'm doing, as also I need to that to be responsive.

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  slidesPerView: 4,
  loopedSlides: 4,
  centeredSlides: false,
  spaceBetween: 10,
  grabCursor: true,
  loop: true,
  pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
  paginationClickable: true,
  breakpoints: {
    1200: {
      slidesPerView: 4,
      loopedSlides: 4,
      spaceBetween: 10
    },
    1024: {
      slidesPerView: 3,
      loopedSlides: 3,
      spaceBetween: 10
    },
    768: {
      slidesPerView: 2,
      loopedSlides: 2,
      spaceBetween: 10
    },
    675: {
      slidesPerView: 1,
      loopedSlides: 1,
      spaceBetween: 20
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

.swiper-slide {
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 100px 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.3.1/js/swiper.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.3.1/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Slider main container -->
<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
  </div>
  <!-- If we need pagination -->
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try setting the option

`slidesPerGroup: 4`

Comment: This answer should be accepted.

It's a proud moment that I was going through API document, I checked many other options but not this one. I just came to this Question and my problem is solved. Keep it up friend.

Comment: Thanks so much for the note! I'm still pretty new to Stacknow exchange and appreciate it.

Comment: I was just away a lot, Thanks.

Comment: Yes! Yesss! Tank you! Tried doing this for AGES without success. Wow Wayne man I love you so much, and you're so far...

Answer (score 1):

If you are lokking for multiple slides to be displayed at a time use

```
slidesPerView: >1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this code:

```
slidesPerGroup: 4,
loopFillGroupWithBlank: true,
```